# The frequency induced by the alternating current

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, everyday-life

Let set up the experiment as followed. A string is stretched at two ends. Two magnet poles N and S are placed under and above the string. Now we let an alternating current go through the string with frequency 50Hz. 
Now with calculation, the frequency of the wave on the string is 100 Hz instead of 50 Hz? Why does it happen?

Comment: Is is possible that 100 Hz is the resonant frequency of the stretched string?